# How can I keep the decimal zeros in a number type variable in TS (Angular )?

Tags: angular, typescript, numbers, decimal

In my case I need to introduce a number in an input, and if the number I introduce in the input has a zero as decimal, for example 5.0 or 34.0, when I pass it to Number in TypeScript it saves it as 5 or 34.

But for the needs of a third party service, I need to pass a 5.0 of type number.

I have tried with `parseFloat(stringValue).toFixed(1)`. This function returns a String with the value I need, but when I parse it to Number, it takes away the decimals.

For example:

```js
let value = "5.0";
let fixedValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(1); // Returns "5.0"

let numberValue = Number(fixedValue);
console.log(numberValue) // Returns 5
```

Has anyone been able to solve this or perform any similar functionality?

Comment: I think that you will have more luck if you share the third party service that you are using and what is the issue you are having, because I don't think that what you are asking is possible nor should it matter, both representations are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript there is no differentiation of integers and floats. All numbers are **inherently floats**. There is no difference between 1 and 1.0, they both shall be treated as equally.

To illustrate

```
1 === 1.0; //true;
parseInt(1) === parseFloat(1.0); //true;
parseFloat(1) === parseFloat(1.0);  //true;
parseInt(1) === parseInt(1.0); //true;
```

The methods like **.toFixed** shall give a **string representation**. Ultimately whenever you convert, it would reduce the fraction part if its only 0.

Answer (score 0):

The fraction part of any decimal is usually reduced if it is **.0**.
But your number still have its decimal capacity and if you need to show it, you have to use **.toFixed(1)** that will return string.
anyway if your input need only to be showed in the template you can use that function to show its fraction part.